# NSString URL decode?

Tags: ios, nsstring, urldecode, percent-encoding

I have tried a lot of approaches out there, but this tiny little string just cannot be URL decoded.

```
NSString *decoded;
NSString *encoded = @"fields=ID%2CdeviceToken";
decoded = (__bridge NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL, (CFStringRef)encoded, NULL, NSUTF8StringEncoding);
NSLog(@"decodedString %@", decoded);
```

The code above just logs the same (!) string after replacing percent escapes.

Is there a reliable solution out there? I think some kind of RegEx solution based on some documentation could work. Any suggestion?

Comment: for swift let decoded = encoded!.stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `CFSTR("")` instead of `NULL` for the second to last argument. From the [CFURL reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html):

> charactersToLeaveEscaped
>
> Characters whose percent escape sequences, such as %20 for a space character, you want to leave intact. Pass NULL to specify that no percent escapes be replaced, or the empty string (CFSTR("")) to specify that all be replaced.

```
    NSString *encoded = @"fields=ID%2CdeviceToken";
    NSString *decoded = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL, (CFStringRef)encoded, CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    NSLog(@"decodedString %@", decoded);
```

Prints:

> 2013-03-26 21:48:52.559 URLDecoding[28794:303] decodedString fields=ID‭,‬deviceToken

Comment: @Carl When I try your code it prints `Decoded String : (null)
` in console. I found the reason. Instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding `, I used `kCFStringEncodingUTF8` and it works.

Answer (score 34):

Another option would be:

```
NSString *decoded = [encoded stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I still have percents in mine after doing this for example. http%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com

Comment: @Alioo This code works for your example in iOS10.1, which system version did you use then? I think implementation of the interface has changed.

Answer (score 14):

***CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding*** is deprecated in iOS 9. Use ***stringByRemovingPercentEncoding*** instead.

```
NSString *decoded = [encoded stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
import Foundation

let charSet = CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.union(.urlQueryAllowed) // just use what you need, either path or query
let enc = "Test Test Test".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: charSet)!
let dec = enc.removingPercentEncoding!

print("Encoded: \(enc)")
print("Decoded: \(dec)")
```

Output:

> Encoded: Test%20Test%20Test
>
> Decoded: Test Test Test